# Openssl creating a certificate from a CSR (No Private Key - Stored in another System)

Tags: openssl

I need to create a certificate based on a `CSR` generated by a third party I have no access to the private key. The certificate generated needs to have 
`keyUsage = keyCertSign` as a minimum as part of the certificate.

```
C:/OpenSSL-Win32/bin/openssl.exe req -in C:/xampp/htdocs/certs/test.csr -out test.cer -config C:/xampp/htdocs/command.cnf
```

Which of course didn't work.

Is this possible? If not can `certreq` be used instead? The `PKI` servers we are using are Microsoft Based.

Comment: `openssl req` can _create_ a CSR, or issue a _selfsigned_ cert (only) from either an existing CSR or the data corresponding to one (and config is needed only in the latter case). `openssl ca` and `openssl x509 -req` are the functions that can issue a CA-signed cert from a CSR -- but only if you have a CA cert and key (and for `ca` a 'database' consisting of two text files). If you want this cert to be able to issue usable child certs, you probably need BC=true as well as KU=certSign.

Answer (score 6):

Given a certificate (ca-cert.pem) and its private key (ca-key.pem), use OpenSSL to sign a provided CSR (csr.pem) and generate a certificate for it (cert.pem) -

```
openssl x509 -req -in csr.pem -out cert.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha256
```

Meaning of options -

- **-CAcreateserial** - serial number would be randomly generated for the certificate (and increased in future activations).
- **-days 365** - certificate would have a validity of 365 days.
- **-sha256** - certificate would use SHA256 as its signature algorithm (which is the default).

To generate such a certificate with "certificate signing" key usage (and also a CA basic constraint, which you probably need), create a configuration file (config.txt) -

```
[extensions]
keyUsage = keyCertSign
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
```

And provide it to OpenSSL as well (pointing to the "extensions" section) -

```
openssl x509 -req -in csr.pem -out cert.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha256 -extfile config.txt -extensions extensions
```

Examine the resulting certificate -

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
```

It has -

```
X509v3 extensions:
  X509v3 Key Usage:
    Certificate Sign
  X509v3 Basic Constraints:
    CA:TRUE
```

For completeness, here is how to create the "provided" CA key, CA self-sign certificate, subject key and CSR (here using RSA keys, EC keys can be used identically) -

CA key -

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca-key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

CA self-signed certificate -

```
openssl req -key ca-key.pem -new -x509 -days 365 -out ca-cert.pem -sha256 -subj /CN=CACert
```

Subject key -

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

CSR for subject key -

```
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem -sha256 -subj /CN=SubjectCert
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the private key, you can create a self signed certificate.  Depending on your situation you may have problems with the certificate being trusted.

If you don't, then need setup a [CA](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/).  If you setup a CA (not that hard) then your problem is that you need to get the CA public key installed into the trusted CA list of all the machines and devices that connects to the server that gives back the certificate you generated.  This is the reason you pay for a "trusted" CA signed certificate as it's there problem to get there root CA certificate installed on as many machines and devices as they can, and also to keep the root CA certificates up to date.